# Integral test for series $\sum_{n = 18}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{(n^3 + 3)^{7/2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

I am stuck on how to more so algebraically to solve this problem. I understand that you would rewrite the series as a function of x, and then evaluate the integral from 18 to infinity - but that's all I got. Any pointers? Thank you in advance.

> Use the integral test to determine whether the infinite series is convergent.
>   $$\sum_{n = 18}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{(n^3 + 3)^{7/2}}.$$

Comment: Yes. So how far have you gotten in computing $$\int_{18}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{(x^3 + 3)^{7/2}} dx \, ?$$ Did you try a substitution?

Comment: Yes, let u=x^3+3, du=3x^2dx. Then the integral of du/(u^7/2). Sorry for the sloppiness -- like I said Im not sure how to type it out on here.

Comment: Ok, so what issue are you running into, then? Can you not compute the integral from there, or do you not know how to interpret the results, or something else?

Comment: I realized I made an arithmetic error while evaluating the integral - thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The integral test states that if the improper integral converges then the sum converges. It is probably nearly impossible to determine what the sum is exactly, but with the integral test, you can show that it is a finite number. The improper integral can be solved using a $u$-substitution of $u=x^3+3$.

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle\int_{18}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{2}}{(x^{3}+3)^{7/2}}dx=\dfrac{1}{3}\dfrac{1}{(-7/2)+1}(x^{3}+2)^{-(7/2)+1}\bigg|_{x=18}^{x=\infty}<\infty$.

One needs to check the monotonicity for $x\rightarrow\dfrac{x^{2}}{(x^{3}+3)^{7/2}}$ on $[18,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$u=x^3+3$$ to evaluate the $$\int_{18}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{(x^3 + 3)^{7/2}} dx$$